# Can I use a PS Vita memory card used with a newer firmware version - on a Vita with a lower?

Tags: ps-vita, ps-vita-tv

I have an *X* PS Vita. X is on firmware 3.61. It has a card. The card contains - say - a digital game purchased on the PlayStation Store, **legally**.

Now, let's say I have a *Y* PS Vita (or PSTV, it doesn't change much) on firmware 3.60.

Both the devices are activated with the same PSN Account, even if the latter doesn't have access to PSN anymore due to Sony's restrictions.

What will happen if I remove the Card from X and put it in Y?

1. Y will recognise the card and games will be playable without any problems. Win!
2. Y will recognise the card but will fail in launching the games due to the license not being verified or whatever. I will be prompted to update. Fail.
3. Y will ask me to erase the card before being able to newly use it. Fail.
4. Something else will happen...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments below, **Option 2.**

*Since you plan on using a cracked, hacked, or software designed to otherwise sidestep the original firmware checks, you are likely to fail. *

Option 1 means you're using stock everything. Cracks and hacks typically come with the guarantee you'll lock yourself out of a certain kind of participation of the manufacturer is keen on keeping you out.

Option 3 is only a possibility of the card is corrupted or the device is faulty.

Comment: Oh. Ok thanks! Even if one of the Vitas is on a firmware where you can't access PSN?

Comment: That will entirely depend on the reason PSN cant be accessed. If it's because it hasn't been disassociated from a previous user account, I believe you'll want to call Sony and have that handled. If it's because you forgot the password, then reset the password on the account and associate them both, first.

Comment: What if it's because the firmware is too old to access PSN?

Comment: Can you update the firmware on it? What is the specific model number of the unit?

Comment: No, I wouldn't be able to install Henkaku on it. Let's say the updated one is a Fat PS Vita and the one on older firmware is a PSTV

Comment: Considering Henkaku is an unlocking software to play homebrew. Homebrew software usually relies on exploiting things firmware hasn't fixed or yet fixed. Generally, your fate is in your hands on this one. It's a crapshoot if you aren't sure and have to ask. That's important information regarding your question to the point it completely changes both the nature of what you've asked and the answer that should have been given.

Comment: I don't totally agree with your statement: I am not asking how to install Henkaku, nor asking for some information directly involving it. One can decide not to update a device too.

Comment: Yes. When you later defined what you were doing and how, is when it changed. Because of the specific nature in what YOU are doing or plan to do, my answer may not be very accurate. For others, sure.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. You mean that once I DO have installed Henkaku, things might change. But until I have no Henkaku installed, the PSTV is still a stock PSTV, so your answer does apply. I don't own the PSTV yet, I'm about to purchase it mostly to play and record some PS Vita games. I'll try to run PS Vita games. If they work, then I'll experiment further. If after installing Henkaku they'll not start anymore, I'll factory reset and start again.